# Value of Memcache location on PythonAnyWhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

What LOCATION should I point Memcached to after deployment on pythonanywhere server? For local I am using this setting and things are working fine.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    } 
}
```

I need to change 'LOCATION' to replace localhost. Any guidance?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: unfortunately we don't provide a memcached server.   If you're using one from a third-party provider, you should get the location details from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can location set to a path.

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': 'unix:~/memcached.sock', }}
```

However, I don't think pythonanywhere lets you use memcache, since you can't use 'sudo apt-get' on a pythonanywhere console, and using memcache requires you to install it. (sudo apt-get install memcached)